# Load connecting tables from Cassandra in QlikView with DataSatx ODBC

Tags: cassandra, datastax, qlikview

I am new to both Cassandra (2.0) and QlikView (11).
I have two keyspaces (tables) with large amount of data in Cassandra and I want to load them to QlikView.
Since I can not load the entire set, filtering is necessary.

```
// In QlikView's edit script
ODBC CONNECT TO [DataStax Cassandra ODBC DSN64];
LOAD idsession,
logintime,
"h_id" as hid;
SQL SELECT *
FROM Cassandra.test.sessions
WHERE logintime > '2015-06-09'
ALLOW FILTERING;

LOAD idhost,
site;
SQL SELECT *
FROM Cassandra.test.hosts
WHERE idhost in hid;
```

The second query does not work, error from qlikview *line 3:16 no viable alternative at input 'hid'*.

**My question**: is it possible to get the h_ids from the first query and only collect the corresponding entities from the second table?

I assume that you can't do an Exists in the DataSyntax ODBC which may help. [DataStax doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html)

This could be done with an external program like (C#) but I really want to do this in QlikView's script file:

```
// Not complete code
query = select * from sessions where loginTime > '2015-06-09';  
foreach (var id in query) {
query2 = "select * from hosts where idhost = " + i;
}
```

**EDIT**
This can be solved when loading XML files:

```
TableA:
LOAD id, 
 itema
FROM
[C:\test1data.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels);

TableB:
LOAD idb, 
 itemb,
 ida
FROM
[C:\test2data.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels) where(Exists (id,ida));
```

**EDIT2**
Besides the great answer from  @i_saw_drones another solutions is to loop through ids.

```
For i = 1 to NoOfRows('Sessions')
 Let cur_id = Peek('hid',i - 1,'Sessions');
 LOAD 
  idhost,
  site;
  SQL SELECT *
  FROM Cassandra.test.hosts
  WHERE idhost = $(cur_id);
NEXT i
```

Nevertheless was the performance not the great. It took about 30 minutes to load around 300 K lines from Cassandra. The same queries were tested in a C# program with the connector and it took 9 sec. But that was just the query. Then you should write it to XML and then load it to QlikView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the second query fails is because the `WHERE` clause is expecting to find a literal string list of values to look "in". For example:

```
LOAD 
    idhost,
    site;
SQL SELECT *
FROM Cassandra.test.hosts
WHERE idhost in ('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4');
```

The `hid` field returned by the first query is a QlikView list and as such cannot be immediately coerced into a string. We have to do a little more scripting to obtain a list of values from the first query in literal form, and then add that to the second query as part of the `WHERE` clause. The easiest way to do this is to concatenate all of your `hid`s into a string and then use the string as part of your `WHERE IN` clause.

```
ODBC CONNECT TO [DataStax Cassandra ODBC DSN64];

MyData:
LOAD
    idsession,
    logintime,
    "h_id" as hid;
SQL SELECT *
FROM Cassandra.test.sessions
WHERE logintime > '2015-06-09'
ALLOW FILTERING;

hid_entries:
LOAD
    chr(39) & hids & chr(39) as hids;
LOAD
    concat(hid, chr(39) & ',' & chr(39)) as hids;
LOAD DISTINCT
    hid
RESIDENT MyData;

LET hid_values = '(' & peek('hids',0,'hid_entries') & ')';

DROP TABLE hid_entries;

LOAD 
    idhost,
    site;
SQL SELECT *
FROM Cassandra.test.hosts
WHERE idhost in $(hid_values);
```

Comment: When I am applying this solution to a table with alot of data it does not scale well. Do you have any tips on other solutions that might scale better?

Comment: If you have a lot of duplicated in the `hid` field, then adding a `DISTINCT` to the `hid_entries` table only loads unique values which can improve performance. As these are `SQL SELECT` statements, you can only use SQL that is compatible with the target provider, so you won't be able to use QV specific functions like `exists` unless you extract the entire `Cassandra.test.hosts` table first.

Comment: I added an alternative solution to the problem.